# Difficulty running pip from command prompt

Tags: command-line, installation, python, pip

I'm trying to install numpy on my computer following the instructions [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/).

I've got the command prompt working to find python after adding it to my path and I installed it from python.org which should have apparently configured pip for usage with installation, but when I try to enter `pip --version` in my command prompt it says that `pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.  Entering `python -m ensurepip --default-pip` yields

```
Looking in links: C:\Users\alecj\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu_bljns8
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\alecj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\alecj\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)
```

which looks like it's there, but I can't check the version or do anything else with it from the command prompt.  How can I get my command prompt to find pip?  I tried adding the above location for pip to my path but it didn't appear to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are my results under a clean install of Windows 10 Home:

When I download python 3.7 from https://www.python.org/downloads/, I can install python from an executable called `python-3.7.0.exe` found in my Downloads folder.  **Make sure to check the box "Add Python 3.7 to PATH"**.

Now, opening the Command Prompt, I can see the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.15]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\nelsn>pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from c:\users\nelsn\appdata\local\programs\python\python37- 
32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

C:\Users\nelsn>python -m ensurepip --default-pip
Looking in links: C:\Users\nelsn\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2wrxm7p6
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\nelsn\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (39.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\nelsn\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)
```

Next, running `pip install requests` definitely works for me.  I can type `python` in the Command Prompt to enter a python repl, and `import requests` just fine.  (Oh, and also `pip install numpy` just fine as well.

Comment: Thank you -- I see `python-3.7.0.exe` in my downloads, but  my command prompt still doesn't find pip; here's a picture http://tinypic.com/r/2ykgx3n/9. Should I just try to reinstall, or is there a picture of some other folders I should show you?

Comment: I recommend that you attempt to reinstall, unless you are absolutely certain that you had checked the box "Add Python 3.7 to PATH", the first time that you tried to perform the installation.

Comment: The reinstall worked perfectly, I must not have checked the box.  Much appreciated!

Comment: It appears that pip successfully installed numpy when I asked it to, but I'm now unable to import numpy to my python scripts -- any simple suggestions, or should I post a separate question?  Here is a pic for reference http://tinypic.com/r/5vsj7c/9.

Comment: This is what I've got so far: https://superuser.com/questions/1337093/difficulty-importing-numpy-into-python-shell-after-installation/1337330#1337330