# Difficulty importing numpy into python shell after installation

Tags: installation, shell, python

After installing numpy through pip in my command prompt then entering a python shell, I can't import numpy into the shell for use. I've uploaded a picture for reference; I have tried restarting my system but it didn't do anything.  What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

EDIT: I've now tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy using pip in the command prompt as suggested in the link below, and python still can't find `numpy` as a module; here is a picture of me doing so then trying to load numpy in a shell.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Seems like there's a lot of related answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321473/how-can-i-import-numpy?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @BenjaminJB Thank you, I'll poke around over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your system is configured differently from mine.  But on a fresh installation of Windows 10 Home, I was able to import numpy without any difficulties.

I installed numpy this way:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of python repl session in Windows 10 PowerShell]

And here is where the package was installed:

[image: Screenshot of python site-packages contents]

Comment: I asked this question over at stackoverflow when it stagnated here, and this is the exact solution recommended over there (it worked like a charm). Thank you!